# Voting a Poll using AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've created a simple poll that would be sent to the server side using AJAX JSON jQuery and would be echoed back. It's not properly working. Please tell me where i've gone wrong. I'm new to jQuery and JSON.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function sendVote(){
    var voteS = $("#vote").val();
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#vote").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "poll_vote.php",
          data : "vote="+voteS,
          dataType: "JSON",
          success : function(data){
            concole.log("Data Submitted " + data);
            $("#result").html(data);
          },
          complete :function(data){},
          error : function(error, data){
            console.log("Error. not Working" + error+" "+ data);
            alert("Error. not Working"+ error);
            $("#result").html(error+ data);
          }
        });
      });   
    });
  }
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$vote = $_POST['vote'];
if (isset($vote)) {
    $list  = array('vote' => $vote);
    $encode = json_encode($list);
 echo $encode;
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <h3> What is your Gender? </h3>
  <form>
    Male : 
    <input type = "radio" name = "vote" value= "0" id="vote" onclick = "return sendVote()" />
    <br />
    Female :
    <input type = "radio" name = "vote" value = "1" id="vote" onclick = "return sendVote()">
  </form>
  <p><div id= "result"></div></p>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not properly working"?

Comment: please post the result

Comment: @maiko ajax `data:` can be a String, Array, or PlanObject http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @ Joe Kennedy i get this error --> "Error. not Working[object Object] parsererror"

Comment: note - `id`s are supposed to be unique, but you have `id="vote"` in both inputs. so `var voteS = $("#vote").val();` will always select only the 1st one. And `$("#vote").click(function(){` will only bind to the 1st one as well.

Comment: Why are you using inline `onclick = "return sendVote()"`, but also doing binding in your function `$("#vote").click(function(){`?

Comment: if not, none of the results will get displayed

Comment: Sorry. The results are now displaying without the sendVote function. My bad. Bu i'm still getting the parsererror error

Answer (score 1):

You have picked ambiguous selector, having used invalid markup with non-unique id.

Change this:

```
var voteS = $("#vote").val();
```

to:

```
var voteS = $("input[name='vote']:checked").val();
```

And, as you specified by `dataType: "JSON"`, you are expecting an json object  in success section, so you only need to access this object's `vote` attribute here:

```
$("#result").html(data.vote);
```

Also in success you have typo: `concole.log` instead of `console.log`

And in your PHP file, you should check if `$_POST['vote']` is set:

```
if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
    $vote = $_POST['vote'];
    $list  = array('vote' => $vote);
    $encode = json_encode($list);
    echo $encode;
}
```

And remove `$(document).ready(function(){` from this function, it will not bind this event to that element before you actually call this function it is in.

Comment: `input[name='vote']` needs to be `input[name='vote']:checked`.

Comment: @n-dru I still get this error --> "Error. not Working[object Object] parsererror " :(

Comment: @AkilaRandil try to remove `$(document).ready(function()` like in my edited answer